# sobre un ejercicio de pl/sql

Tags: plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE orden (n1 IN OUT number, n2 IN OUT number, n3 IN OUT number) AS
    menor number;
    mediano number;
    mayor number;
BEGIN
    IF n1 < n2 THEN
        IF n2 < n3 THEN
            mediano := n2;
            mayor   := n3;
            IF n1 < n3 THEN
                menor := n1;
            END IF;
        ELSE
            mediano := n3;
            mayor   := n2;
        END IF;
    ELSE
        menor := n3;
        mediano := n1;
        mayor := n2;    
    END IF;
    ELSE
        IF n1 < n3 THEN
            menor := n3;
            mediano := n1;
            mayor := n2;
        END IF;
    ELSE
        mayor := n1;
        IF n2 < n3 THEN
            mediano := n2;
            menor := n1;
        END IF;
    ELSE
        mediano := n2;
        menor   := n1;

    END IF;
    n1 := menor;
    n2 := mediano;
    n3 := mayor;    
END;
/
```

y me dice que tengo error en las siguientes lineas:

> 22/1   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ELSE" when expecting one of
>   the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if
>   loop mod   null pragma raise return select update while with         
>   << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback
>   savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge
>
> 28/1   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ELSE" when expecting one of
>   the following:
>
> LINE/COL ERROR
>   -------- -----------------------------------------------------------------     ( begin case declare end exit for goto if loop mod null     pragma raise
>   return select update while with       <<     continue close current
>   delete fetch lock insert open rollback     savepoint set sql execute
>   commit forall merge pipe purge
>
> 34/1   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ELSE" when expecting one of
>   the following:     ( begin case declare end exit for goto if loop mod
>   null   pragma raise return select update while with 
>     <<
>
> LINE/COL ERROR
>   -------- -----------------------------------------------------------------     continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
>   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
>
> 39/1   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "N1" 42/4     PLS-00103:
>   Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting    one of the
>   following:     end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static
>      member constructor map

Answer (score 2):

Como su error indica, estás haciendo mal el cierre de la condición. En concreto en el EndIF de la linea 21 estás cerrando la condición de

```
  IF n1 < n2 THEN
```

Es por ello, que el ELSE de la linea 22 te devuelve error, al no tener un condicional al que asociarse.

A partir de esa linea, tienes varios "ELSE" que no cuelgan sobre ninguna condición .Varios puntos a tener en cuenta aquí:

1: Eso es incorrecto, el "ELSE" está hecho para cubrir todos los casos que no se hayan cubierto en las condiciones anteriores. En su lugar, usa la sentencia elsif (condición). Dejando un único else para el caso genérico que no cumpla de las condiciones expuestas.

2: De cara a código más grande, la estructura básica para crear condicionales  es la siguiente

```
if (condicion1) then
-- Lo que sea
elsif (condicion2) then
-- lo que sea si se cumple la condición
elsif (condicionN) then
-- lo que sea si se cumple
else -- sin condicion
-- Caso si no es ninguno de los anteriores
end if;
```

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Tu código esta muy mal la verdad es muy lioso y tedioso por eso no te lo puedo reparar pero te voy a poner como lo haría yo con dos opciones.

**1º) Ejemplo**

```
USE PRUEBA; # Usar una bd
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS PINTAENORDEN $$
CREATE PROCEDURE PINTAENORDEN(IN num1 INT, IN num2 INT, IN num3 INT)
BEGIN
    IF (((num1 < num2) OR (num1 = num2)) AND ((num1 < num3) OR (num1 = num3))) THEN
        IF (num2 < num3) THEN
            SELECT concat('Numeros ORDENADOS : ',num1,', ',num2,', ',num3);
        ELSE
            SELECT concat('Numeros ORDENADOS : ',num1,', ',num3,', ',num2);
        END IF;
    ELSEIF (((num2 < num1) OR (num2 = num1)) AND ((num2 < num3) OR (num2 = num3))) THEN
         IF (num1 < num3) THEN
            SELECT concat('Numeros ORDENADOS : ',num2,', ',num1,', ',num3);
        ELSE
            SELECT concat('Numeros ORDENADOS : ',num2,', ',num3,', ',num1);
        END IF;
    ELSEIF (((num3 < num1) OR (num3 = num1)) AND ((num3 < num2) OR (num3 = num2))) THEN
         IF (num1 < num2) THEN
            SELECT concat('Numeros ORDENADOS : ',num3,', ',num1,', ',num2);
        ELSE
            SELECT concat('Numeros ORDENADOS : ',num3,', ',num2,', ',num1);
        END IF;
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Te explico un poco lo que hace este código primero uso una base de datos para poder ejecutarlo, luego cambio el **delimitador a $$** es decir en lugar de terminar **en ;** termina **en $$**.

Luego si **el procedimiento existe pues lo borra** para poder crearlo posteriormente.

Luego lo creamos con los **3 parámetros de tipo INT (Numérico)**.

Hacemos los IF, ELSEIF y ELSE correspondiente con lo que yo hice aquí también te lo ordena en caso de que coincida los números.

Cambiamos el **Delimitador de nuevo a ;**

Si lo quieres llamar debes usar **`call PINTAENORDEN(5,3,4);`** por ejemplo con los números que desees

**2º) Ejemplo**

```
DELIMITER $$
USE prueba $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS PINTAENORDEN $$
CREATE PROCEDURE PINTAENORDEN (IN num1 INT,IN num2 INT,IN num3 INT)
BEGIN
     DECLARE intercambio_1 INT;
     DECLARE intercambio_2 INT;
     DECLARE intercambio_3 INT;
     IF (num1>num2) THEN
         SET intercambio_1=num2;
         SET num2=num1;
         SET num1=intercambio_1;
         IF (num1>num3) THEN
             SET intercambio_2=num3;
             SET num3=num1;
             SET num1=intercambio_2;
             IF (num2>num3) THEN
                 SET intercambio_3=num3;
                 SET num3=num2;
                 SET num2=intercambio_3;
             END IF;
         ELSE
             IF (num2>num3) THEN
                 SET intercambio_2=num3;
                   SET num3=num2;
                 SET num2=intercambio_2;
             END IF;
         END IF;
     ELSE
         IF (num2>num3) THEN
             SET intercambio_1=num3;
             SET num3=num2;
             SET num2=intercambio_1;
         END IF;
     END IF;
     SELECT num1,num2,num3;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Este segundo método de ordenamiento se le conoce como el de la **burbuja**.

Se declara 3 variables para poder realizarlo.

El ***ordenamiento de burbuja (Bubble Sort en inglés)*** es un sencillo algoritmo de ordenamiento. ***Funciona revisando cada elemento de la lista que va a ser ordenada con el siguiente, intercambiándolos de posición si están en el orden equivocado***. Es necesario revisar varias veces toda la lista hasta que no se necesiten más intercambios, lo cual significa que la lista está ordenada. Este algoritmo obtiene su nombre de la forma con la que suben por la lista los elementos durante los intercambios, como si fueran pequeñas "burbujas". También es conocido como el método del intercambio directo. Dado que solo usa comparaciones para operar elementos, se lo considera un algoritmo de comparación, siendo uno de los más sencillos de implementar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haberte sido de ayuda y saludos.